# How to make responsive cards as shown below?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having some problem with that black box with date. I made it but it isn't responsive.

[image]

```css
.date
{
  width: 20%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card up" style="width:400px height:400px">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/1900x1400" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="date">
      
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is that image not too big? And give the date div a text

Comment: So, if you made it, why not make it responsive like the other parts of your design? How should we know what is missing if you haven't defined the function?

Comment: are you asking for help or `hey can you do this for me ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `position-absolute` for the card-body
- Put the date inside the card-body and give it negative top value.

---

#### Fixed size

```css
.date {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto ">
      <div class="card up" style="width:400px height:400px">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/1900x1400" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card-body position-relative pt-5">
          <div class="date position-absolute"></div>
          <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Relative size

```css
.date {
  width: 3.8888888889em;
  height: 3.8888888889em;
  background-color: black;
  top: -1.9em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto ">
      <div class="card up" style="width:400px height:400px">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/1900x1400" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card-body position-relative pt-5">
          <div class="date position-absolute"></div>
          <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKzQez

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

---

You can also do this with negative margin too.

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand the issue of this case first. As you have added width: 100% to the image, this has a responsive height. Therefore, `.card` doesn't have a fix height. When you use `top: 40%` (percentage value), this breaks the view.

Solution;
wrap image and `.date` inside another div.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width: 100%;" alt="Card image">
   <div class="date"></div>
</div>
```

And, set `bottom: - 20%` or appropreate value instead of `top: 40%` for `.date` class. 
Hope this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to respecify the width and height of 'card' and 'up' classes (missing semicolumn).

Then with the actual code snippet i can't clearly see what is wrong, but if you have responsive problem with absolute positioning, try to add "position: relative" to your container so the absolute elements won't overflow their parent block.